# Is there a way I can render a 2 level nested component in Angular using `router-outlet`?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a sidebar with some links. The sidebar is located at the `/dashboard` route. The links on the sidebar are direct children to `/dashboard`. I now want to render the children of `/dashboard` inside the main `router-outlet`. I have no idea on how to approach this.
The following are some code snippets to elaborate my question further

**My routing structure**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'roles',
        component: RolesComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'workgroups',
        component: WorkgroupsComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'savewg',
            component: WgDetailsComponent,
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'users',
        component: UsersComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

**App component**

```
<!-- Main app component -->
<div class="app-view">
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**Login.html**

```
<button mat-raised-button color="warn" class="login-field" (click)="login(email, password)"
            <!-- rest of code ommited for brevity  -->
```

**Login.ts**

```
public login(email: string, password: string) {
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard'], { replaceUrl: true });
  }
```

**Workgroup Component html**

```
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" [routerLink]="['savewg']">
            <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
              New
        </button>
       <!-- Code ommited for brevity -->

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="workgroup-filters">
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <!-- rest of Code ommited for brevity -->
```

- When I click on the `new` button in the `workgroup` component, I want it to navigate me to the `savewg` component view and replace the content in the `workgroup` component.
- Any suggestions on how I can tackle this will be appreciated

Comment: Just for clarity, you want to have an additional router outlet in `WorkgroupsComponent` where all the children of `workgroups` will be rendered.  Is this correct?

Comment: @JasonWhite Yes, that is exactly what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are only allow one main `router-outlet` per module.  You will have to create a separate module for `workgroups` path and lazy load it.  The `workgroups` module will have its own routing file and its own router outlet where you will load all your routes from your `workgroup` module.  **See below stackblitz for a working example.**

#### app-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  {
    path: 'workgroups',
    loadChildren: () => import('./workgroups/workgroups.module').then(m => m.WorkgroupsModule)
  },
  ...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

#### workgroups-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WorkgroupsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'savewg',
        component: WgDetailsComponent
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'savewg',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class WorkgroupsRoutingModule { }
```

#### workgroups.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    WorkgroupsRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    WorkgroupsComponent, 
    WgDetailsComponent
    ]
})
export class WorkgroupsModule { }
```

Below are resources for lazy loading modules and a stackblitz example.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hbogtn

> https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-nested-routing-with-multiple-routeroutlet-using-loadchildren-having-own-router-modules-example-application/#.X3IQa3WYXmE

Comment: This is a good approach but applying it to my project breaks alot of stuff. I found another way and it's in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution to this. It turns out that Angular will load the empty path route as the default route and there is no need to worry about router outlet anymore. I modified my `app-routing.module.ts` in the following way:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'roles',
        component: RolesComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'workgroups',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'savewg',
            component: WgDetailsComponent,
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: WorkgroupsComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: 'users',
        component: UsersComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

- As you can see, I've added an empty path as a child in the
  `workgroups component` This may not be perfect, more approaches and
  solutions are welcome.